# Is there a better way to escape slashes in a string in POSIX sh

Tags: replace, sh, posix

This function works, but I am thinking there *must* be a more elegant way to convert all '/' to '\/' (so that I can subsequently feed it into sed using the standard '/' for substitute):

```
escapeslash() {
    val="$1"    
    fixed=""
    while [ 1 ]; do
        start=${val%%/*}
        remainder=${val#*/}
        if [ "${remainder}" = "${val}" ]; then
            fixed="${fixed}${start}"
            break;
        fi
        fixed="${fixed}${start}\/"
        val="${remainder}"  
    done    
    echo "${fixed}" 
}
```

Comment: What kind of strings you usually encounter? Provide a few samples!

Comment: as an example, if I do:
`x=\`escapeslash "/tmp/file"`\`
it will set x to:
`"\/tmp\/file"`
This is what I want so that i can subsequently call sed. My code does:
`val=\`escapeslash "${val}"\`;error=\`echo "${error}" | sed "s/${delim}/${val}/"\` `
With this routine, I can be confident that sed will be 'happy' because I am escaping the '/'

Comment: Simpler solution is to use alternative substitution delimiters, e.g. `sed "s#${delim}#${val}#"`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/10971581

Comment: David - good idea but in my case I don't know what text will be in 'val' - and since it could have a # in it, that would just create a different problem.

Comment: Thank you I0b0 and jhnc. That's what I was after. Never thought to use sed to fix the input to sed!